# Facebook js share bug in facebook APP

Tags: facebook, share

I  created a Facebook js share at `www.laobi.info` and  I can get the result when I shared  it successfully in PC and mobile. But I can't get the result when I  open the `www.laobi.info` and shared it in Facebook APP. I tried Android and iPhone, they returned the different results after I shared it  successfully. I don't know why. Maybe it's a bug.

- First, I login in Facebook App,
- Second, I search the link: `www.laobi.info` and open it.
- Third, I click the 'share', but I can't get the result though I successfully shared. However, I can get the result when I share it successfully in PC and mobile’s browser.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you need to know if it shared successful?

Comment: Because the user will redirect the other page after it shared successfully.If failed ,the user will stay the current page.

Comment: That is not allowed. You are not allowed to gate the user depending if they shared or not